# Unable to post the form data to controller

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, knockout.js, knockout-mvc

Model: I have a view with collection of addresses and names. I know i am missing something but not able to figure out. I am new to knockout trying to create some sample from using mvc. I see null values coming in the controller. Here is the fiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/iamsrk/9kf41vd7/32/

```
     public class PersonModel
        {
            public virtual ICollection<NameModel> NameModel { get; set; } = new HashSet<NameModel>();
            public virtual ICollection<AddressModel> AddressModel { get; set; } = new HashSet<AddressModel>();
        }

        public class NameModel
        {
            public string FirstName { get; set; }
            public string MiddleName { get; set; }
            public string LastName { get; set; }
            public string Gender { get; set; }
            public string Suffix { get; set; }
        }
        public class AddressModel
        {
            public string FirstName { get; set; }
            public string MiddleName { get; set; }
            public string LastName { get; set; }
            public string ReportingDate { get; set; }
            public string Gender { get; set; }
            public string Suffix { get; set; }
        }
```

Controller Action:

```
public ActionResult GetPerson(PersonModel personModel)
        {
            return null;
        }
```

View:

```
  <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <div class="panel panel-info">
                <div class="panel-heading">
                    <h1 class="panel-title">
                        Names
                    </h1>
                </div>
                <div data-bind="with: nameModel" class="panel-body">
                    <table class="table table-hover table-responsive">
                        <thead>
                            <tr>
                                <th>First</th>
                                <th>Middle</th>
                                <th>Last</th>
                                <th>Suffix</th>
                                <th>Gender</th>
                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody data-bind="foreach: names">
                            <tr>
                                <td>
                                    <input class="form-control" data-bind="value: firstName" />
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    <input class="form-control" data-bind="value: middleName" />
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    <input class="form-control" data-bind="value: lastName" />
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    <input class="form-control" data-bind="value: suffix" />
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    <input class="form-control" data-bind="value: gender" />
                                </td>
                                <td style="vertical-align: inherit;"><a href="#" data-bind="click:$parent.removeName.bind($data)">Delete</a></td>
                            </tr>
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                    <button class="btn btn-success btn-sm" data-bind="click: addName.bind($data)">Add Name</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <div class="panel panel-info">
                <div class="panel-heading">
                    <h1 class="panel-title">
                        Addresses
                    </h1>
                </div>
                <div data-bind="with: addressModel" class="panel-body">
                    <table class="table table-hover table-responsive">
                        <thead>
                            <tr>
                                <th>street</th>
                                <th>city</th>
                                <th>state</th>
                                <th>country</th>
                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody data-bind="foreach:names">
                            <tr>
                                <td>
                                    <input class="form-control" data-bind="value: street" />
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    <input class="form-control" data-bind="value: city" />
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    <input class="form-control" data-bind="value: state" />
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    <input class="form-control" data-bind="value: country" />
                                </td>
                                <td style="vertical-align: inherit;"><a href="#" data-bind="click:$parent.removeAddress.bind($data)">Delete</a></td>
                            </tr>
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                    <button class="btn btn-success btn-sm" data-bind="click: addAddress.bind($data)">Add Address</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <button id="saveButton" type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-company pull-right" data-bind="click: save">
        Save
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-download-alt"> </span>
    </button>
```

KnockOut Script:

```
<script>
    var NameModel = function(names) {
        var self = this;
        self.addName = function() {
            self.names.push({
                firstName: "",
                middleName: "",
                lastName: "",
                suffix: "",
                gender: ""
            });
        };
        self.removeName = function(name) {
            self.names.remove(name);
        };
        if (names != null)
            self.names(names);
    };
    var AddressModel = function(addresses) {
        var self = this;
        self.names = ko.observableArray(addresses);

        self.addAddress = function() {
            self.names.push({
                street: "",
                city: "",
                state: "",
                country: ""
            });
        };
        self.removeAddress = function(address) {
            self.names.remove(address);
        };
        if (addresses != null)
            self.names(addresses);
    };
    var viewModel = {
        nameModel: new NameModel([
            {
                firstName: "",
                middleName: "",
                lastName: "",
                suffix: "",
                gender: ""
            }
        ]),
        addressModel: new AddressModel([
            {
                street: "",
                city: "",
                state: "",
                country: ""
            }
        ]),
        save: function () {
            var self = this;
            $.ajax({
                url: '@Url.Action("GetPerson", "Person")',
                type: 'POST',
                contentType: 'application/json',
                data: ko.toJSON({ PersonModel: self
        })
            });
        }
    };
    ko.applyBindings(viewModel);

</script>
```

Comment: Change your knockout data property to `{ personModel: self }` (lowercase 'P').  This property name should be identical to the parameter name on the controller, which in C# is case sensitive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This

```
data: ko.toJSON({ PersonModel: self })
```

will send this

```
{ PersonModel: { nameModel: { names: [...] }, addressModel: { addresses: [...] } }
```

which does not match your C# classes.  You want to send this

```
{ nameModel: [...], addressModel: [...] }
```

because in JSON the root object is not named and your C# class does not have a `names` or `addresses` property.  Try

```
data: ko.toJSON({ nameModel: self.nameModel.names,
                  addressModel: self.addressModel.addresses })
```

Also, POSTing to a controller action called "GetPerson" is a really bad idea.  And your address model has an observable array called `names`, which I assume is a copy-paste error.

Comment: I agree on all your points except the first - I believe his issue is the capitalization in `{ PersonModel: self }`.  If you only have one parameter on the controller action you are absolutely right that he does not *have* to provide the name of the parameter, but it is not a bad practice to provide it because if there are multiple parameters then it is good practice to always send the names of what maps to what.  [Here is an example question and answer of what I am talking about](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17483177/594354)

Comment: to claify my point of the capitalization issue - C# is case sensitive, and the name `PersonModel` is not going to map to the parameter `personModel` on the action

Comment: "Case-insensitive property deserialization" http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/JsonNetVsDotNetSerializers.htm

Comment: there is nothing here saying he is using Json.Net - I'm a huge proponent of Json.Net too, but I think that the discussion of that is beyond the scope of the original question lol

Comment: but my point also isn't that you can get around the case sensitivity - it's why he *should* include the property name when sending data for good practice.  If his controller has more than one parameter then the deserializer (whether or not Json.Net) will not be able to map the object properties correctly

Comment: @PaulAbbott why is posting to a controller action is a bad idea?

Comment: A controller action called ***Get***Person that actually *saves* a person is a very poor naming convention.

Comment: @PaulAbbott i got you. I was actually trying to create some sample application to learn knockout. So, was creating names randomly but ya i agree completely with you. Thanks!